# setting up environment variable in travis

Tags: firebase, travis-ci, gatsby

I am building a react app.

In my react app I have environment variables which I am acessing using process.env

Something like this

```
firebase.initializeApp({
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSANGER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.REACT_APP_MEASUREMENT_ID,
});
```

I want these variables to have value when gatsby is making my production build , I am not sure if this is correct, but I have added them in settings in my travis. Is this correct? Will my react have access to above variables?

**Update:** They aren't accessible in travis with above approach. so can someone help me in comprehending on how to set react variables in travis?

[image]

I aslo want to deploy by static site it to firebase hosting, In the above image, the first name is firebase which contains my firebase token.

How can I access that token in my travis cli?

Update: Here is how my travis.yml looks like

```
language: node_js
node_js: -"node"
before_script: -"npm install firebase-tools -g"
  -"npm install gatsby -g"
  -"npm install"
script: -"npm run develop"
after_success: -"firebase deploy --token=${firebase}"
```

Comment: are u using webpack? if so, are you setting the env variables into it?

Comment: @andresmijares project was creating using gatsby boiler plate. I can access the .env variables in localhost but not on deployment. Updating question

Comment: I've seen this in the past, maybe when you are generating the build the variables are not available, I would suggest to encrypt them, take a look at the docs https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/

Comment: Did you make sure to set up env variables properly in your Gatsby site? https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/environment-variables/